# Java BufferedReader IO Error. Stream Close

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I made a tictactoe project that allow human to play against computer.
The program will read the list of things like:

```
xxxd
----
----
----
```

from the text file and match these with the main chess board to get the move step for the computer. This move step is marked 'D' in the list above.

I wrote a simple piece of java code to get input from keyboard, but it keeps printing out IO Error.

I run at debug mode. Below is the stacktrace

```
    package net.luan.controller;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import net.luan.bean.MainBoard;
    import net.luan.bean.Position;
    import net.luan.util.ProjectProperties;
    import net.luan.util.StepValidation;

    public class HumanController {

    private char humanName = ProjectProperties.HUMAN_NAME;

    public HumanController() {

    }

    public void makeMoveStep(MainBoard mainBoard) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        StepValidation validator = new StepValidation();
        try {
            Position moveStep = this.inputMoveStep(br);
            boolean true_flag = validator.isStepValid(moveStep, mainBoard);
            while (!true_flag) {
                this.inputMoveStep(br);
            }
            mainBoard.setPosition(moveStep);
            System.out.println("Human: (" + moveStep.getX() + ", " + moveStep.getY() + ")");
            br.close();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Hay nhap vao so nguyen.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Position inputMoveStep(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        Position movePosition = new Position();
        String str;
        System.out.print("Input X: ");

/*It stops right here and turns out an IO Erro*/

        str = br.readLine();        int x = Integer.parseInt(str); 
        System.out.print("Input Y: ");
        str = br.readLine();
        int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
        movePosition.setName(humanName);
        movePosition.setX(x);
        movePosition.setY(y);
        return movePosition;
    }

    }


    /*And it is called by the MainController.*/

    /**
     * MainController
     */
    package net.luan.controller;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import net.luan.bean.MainBoard;
    import net.luan.logic.WinCheckingLogic;


    public class MainController {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainBoard mainBoard = new MainBoard();

        ComputerController computerController = new ComputerController();
        HumanController humanController = new HumanController();

        WinCheckingLogic winCheck = new WinCheckingLogic();

        boolean isContinue = true;
        boolean isWinMove = false;

        char inputChar;

        mainBoard.boardInitialize();
        mainBoard.drawBoard();

        try {
            System.out.println("who play first? Human? Y: ");
            inputChar = getConfirmChar();
            while (isContinue == true) {
                if (inputChar == 'Y' || inputChar == 'y') {
                    while (isWinMove == false) {
                        humanController.makeMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        mainBoard.drawBoard();
                        isWinMove = winCheck.isWinMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        if (isWinMove == true) {
                            System.out.println("You Won.");
                            isContinue = false;
                        }

                        computerController.makeMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        mainBoard.drawBoard();
                        isWinMove = winCheck.isWinMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        if (isWinMove) {
                            System.out.println("Computer Won.");
                            isContinue = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    while (isWinMove == false) {
                        computerController.makeMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        mainBoard.drawBoard();
                        isWinMove = winCheck.isWinMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        if (isWinMove) {
                            System.out.println("Computer Won.");
                            isContinue = false;
                        }

                        humanController.makeMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        mainBoard.drawBoard();
                        isWinMove = winCheck.isWinMoveStep(mainBoard);
                        if (isWinMove == true) {
                            System.out.println("You Won.");
                            isContinue = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Y: ");
                inputChar = getConfirmChar();
                if (inputChar == 'Y' || inputChar == 'y') {
                    isContinue = true;
                } else {
                    isContinue = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("OI Error");
        }
    }

    public static char getConfirmChar() throws IOException {
        char ch = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str;
        boolean again = true;
        while (again) {
            str = br.readLine();
            if (str.length() == 1) {
                again = false;
                ch = str.charAt(0);
            } else {
                again = true;
                System.out.println("Khong hop le, nhap lai!");
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return ch;
    }
    }

StackTrace

Input X: IO Error.
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at net.luan.controller.HumanController.inputMoveStep(HumanController.java:52)
    at net.luan.controller.HumanController.makeMoveStep(HumanController.java:32)
    at net.luan.controller.MainController.main(MainController.java:67)
```

I think this a simple mistake, but i can't figure out. Give me some hint please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You piped the text file in? Maybe the multiple BufferedReader instances are causing the problem. They first getConfirmChar() is consuming the file content up into the buffer, but you read just 1 line. Afterwards in inputMoveStep() you are already at end of file. Please try to remove all of the BufferedReader creations and replace the reads by `str = System.console().readLine();`